# Replace all text words with hyperlink list in word

Tags: vba, text, replace, hyperlink, ms-word

I have a number of lengthy Word 2010 documents riddled with acronyms and many of the same acronyms are common to all these docs. I also have a vertical list of these acronyms that are in hyperlink format within each document in a table format (at then end of each document).

e.g. Hyperlink list:

```
AA1
AA2
AA3
...
```

I have very little Word 2010 macro experience but wonder if it's possible to have a macro that would work like this:

1. Within any given doc, when I place my cursor on the top of the list (i.e. at the cell with hyperlink contents "AA1"), it would select the contents of this first cell, then copy it to clipboard, then do a global replace (using ^c I suppose) of all text formatted words "AA1" within the document with the hyperlink formatted word "AA1" (assuming it found the word to replace).
2. It would then move down to the second cell with a hyperlink content of "AA2" and replace all "AA2" text within the document with the hyperlinked "AA2" value etc. until all the hyperlinked words in the hyperlinked list have replaced all the text words within the document.

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your mean correct [Question was not clear and visual] this is the base code that you need:

```
Sub replaceHyperLink()
Dim searchText As String
searchText = "AA1"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .text = ""
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

Do
    With Selection.Find
    .text = searchText
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
        "stackoverflow.com/", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=searchText
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

- you must do it in loop for AA2,AA3,....
- if you want to hyperlink just    one column of table, select that
  column and then copy it in new document (code for do that is simple)
  then do operation and again paste it in selected column.

and if you want to get text from cells:

```
Dim cellText As String
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(i).Cells(3).Select
cellText = Selection.text
'do what you want with text
Next i
```

Comment: Solivan - many thanks for this! I like it very much! Is there a way for searchText to NOT be hard coded as "AA1", and simply set itself to the value of the cell that the cursor is in? The reason I ask is that I would like to place the cursor on the top cell in the column (in my example this would be "AA1" but in reality it could be anything (e.g. AB1, AAA, ACK) and once it has performed your code, the cursor would go down to the next cell, use its value and do the replacement etc.  etc.). Then I could copy this generic table to any completed document, run the macro to update all the acronyms.

Comment: UR welcome. yes it is possible with simple codes. see edited post

Comment: I have a similar script I am trying to debug (1st half is below)              Sub replaceHyperLinkO
, replaceHyperLink Macro
Dim cellText As String
cellText = Selection.Text
Selection.Copy
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection. Find. Replacement.Clea rFormatting
With Selection.Find
.Text = celiText
.Replacement.Text = "lie"
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindAsk
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAIIWordForms = False
End With

Comment: second half is....
With Selection. Find
.Text = cellText
End With
Do While Selection.Find.Found = True
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables{I}.Rows.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables{I}.Rows{i}.Cells{l}.Select
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAII
Next i
Loop
End Sub

Comment: it almost runs (global replacement within the document of any text matching the cell value where my cursor happens to be sitting within the table column with works quite well), but being a novice, I cannot get the loop to work for the next "i". Unfortunately I have made some many changes i c an't wseem to debug this mess. Thoughts?

Comment: OK. i dont suggest wdreplaceall. because you want to add hyperlink to texts